# An Honest Confession

Tags: riddle, word, enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

> This life of mine is quite the puzzle.
>
> No one, not even those closest to me, knows the truth.
>
> But I do know the truth exists within me.
>
> I just don't know how to be true.

Hint #1:

> There is only one correct interpretation. No one-word answers, please — give an explanation.

Hint #2:

> “The most important thing in communication is hearing what isn’t said.”  - Peter Drucker

Hint #3:

> I want to tell you what I've kept hidden, but I'm afraid.

Comment: Are you sure this is tagged correctly? I was thinking [tag:riddle] and maybe [tag:enigmatic-puzzle], but not sure if there's some hidden meaning in the tagging.

Comment: If a puzzle contains no question, can it have an answer?

Comment: If you were to ask me, “What is this puzzle about?”, I would say that is the question.

Comment: `the truth exists within me` - could you please confirm there's no `steganography` tag required?

Comment: @Phylyp That is a great question. I’ve added the steganography tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a good one. I believe the confession in the answer is that:

> the person writing the text is **gay**

That's a clever arrangement of words to make it a decent poem too.

> 'g', 'a', 'y' are the only letters of the alphabet missing from the text.

It was a shot in the dark, but it's the Peter Drucker quote that led me in this direction.

> Funnily enough, the Julia program I wrote to get the missing alphabets (which was programmed only to print out the Set of missing alphabets, in whatever order) just straight away printed `Set(['g', 'a', 'y'])`. :)

Comment: Your shot in the dark brought you to the correct answer! Thank you for the kind words.

Answer (score 2):

Could you be

> A magic 8 ball? (Or analogously a paper fortune teller)

No one, not even those closest to me, knows the truth.

> They bring their questions to you for they do not know the answer themselves.

But I do know the truth exists within me.

> The magic 8 ball contains all possible answers (yes, no, maybe, etc) so one must be the truth.

I just don't know how to be true.

> You just don't know which answer is the true one. You can shake the magic 8 ball, but it just selects a random one.

Comment: I think this answer would fit if this was a simple "what am I?" riddle, but the nature of this particular puzzle and how it should be solved is different.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this is incorrect, but I figured I'd try a different approach at least. How about a:

> [Thaumatrope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thaumatrope)

"*This life of mine is quite the puzzle.*"

> While not technically alive, it is not immediately apparent how a Thaumatrope works.

"*No one, not even those closest to me, knows the truth.*"

> Both the front and back of a thaumatrope do not give you the full picture.

"*But I do know the truth exists within me.*"

> All the letters in the word `truth` are also in the word `thaumatrope`, and also spinning the thaumatrope combines the two pictures to reveal the true picture.

"*I just don't know how to be true.*"

> Again referring to their usage / true picture not being immediately apparent?

Again, I don't expect this to be correct, but I hit a dead end and wanted to tell you where I ended up anyway.

Comment: Nice attempt, I see you really thought this through. Unfortunately the correct answer is something very different.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. Curious what it'll end up being!

Answer (score 1):

Could you be a

> Compulsive Liar

This life of mine is quite the puzzle.

> A Compulsive Liar has no good reason to lie so frequently making it a "puzzle"

No one, not even those closest to me, knows the truth.

> A Compulsive Liar will lie to just about everyone except to himself

But I do know the truth exists within me.

> A Compulsive Liar knows the true but fails to say it

I just don't know how to be true.

> Sometimes Compulsive Liars don't lie because they choose so, it's the only thing they know how to do. 
>  "Many compulsive liars begin telling lies to avoid reality or certain perceptions they have about themselves."

Comment: Unfortunately I am looking for something different.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be:

> An answer

This life of mine is quite the puzzle.

> answers exists because there are puzzles

No one, not even those closest to me, knows the truth.

> Sometimes the answers we get don't show the truth

But I do know the truth exists within me.

> There is some truth in all answers

I just don't know how to be true.

> Answers need to be verified

By similar logic

> theory or hypothesis also works

Answer (score 0):

It could be a

> a dumb and blind witness to a crime (which s/he can make out by his/her other senses).

As,

> such a witness cannot narrate the incident to establish the truth.

Comment: Good attempt, but there is a different way to approach this puzzle. You would need to look more closely.